# ActionBar цвет фона

Tags: java, android, actionbar

Всем привет. Как поменять цвет фона ActionBar ( или toolbar не знаю как правильно)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если по быстрому то, выставляете цвет который вам нужен в `colors.xml`

```
<color name="myColor">#80808080</color>
```

Указываете свой цвет в `styles.xml`

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/myColor</item>
```

конец!

Второй вариант

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

Comment: я вот именно не хоче цвет primary менять нельзя как то по другому?

Comment: Изменения вступят в силу если только вы меняете тот стиль который используете, например `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>`, а в AndroidManifest.xml установлен `android:theme="@style/AppTheme">`

Comment: я не хочу менять стиль. Можно как то программно?

Comment: В ответе добавил второй вариант

Comment: круто. Спасибо большое